# 80's or 90's "Dungeon" magazine adventure - players are shipwrecked on a noble's island, and attend a party

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, product-identification

My daughter is home for college and has asked her friends over to play (and me to DM).
A request was made for a combat-light short adventure with mystery elements.

I am trying to remember a specific *Dungeon* magazine adventure, I believe from the late '80's or earliest 90's.  Could be 1e, 2e, or BECMI.

The players survive a shipwreck and land on the island of a minor noble / wealthy merchant.

The noble (?) is hosting a party and something mysterious is going on among the invited guests that the PC's can investigate (possibly a murder or disappearance?)

There are a number of different NPC's to have social interactions with - much of the adventure involves questioning witnesses and comparing stories.

There may be a set of female twins among the guests to confuse things.

There is some sort of shape-changing monster like a mimic or protein polymorph in the manor house.

Title and/or issue number would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is [DragonDex](https://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/) which " accounts for all information from issues of Dragon, all seven issues of The Strategic Review, and the Dragon Annual special editions that were released each November from 1996 to 2001." Make sure to post the answer if you dig it up yourself.

Comment: @Ifusaso That's a great resource, but I am sure it was _Dungeon_, not _Dragon_.

Comment: This [Dungeon magazine adventure index](http://www.purpleworm.org/tools/DungeonMagazineIndex.htm) might be of more use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It was a Baron, specifically

The AD&D adventure "Stranded on the Baron's Island" by Willie Walsh (*Dungeon*, issue 14, p. 19-34) matches your description to a T. [Tenfootpole](https://tenfootpole.org/ironspike/?p=2238)'s description:

> Country House Murder, except its a theft and the party is shipwrecked. (No Murder Hobo would be caught dead sailing; the ships are always wrecking.) Lots of people with things to hide and quirky behavior, so lots of red herrings. Nice use of a mimic & doppleganger which is mostly wasted in this thing. The NPC’s are strong, but the formatting suffers: its arranged like a location based adventure instead of a social adventure. A HEAVY edit could save this. Which would be a lot of work.

It's available on [Annarchive](https://annarchive.com/) ([direct download](https://annarchive.com/files/Dungeon%20Magazine%20%23014.pdf) link).

Comment: [Baron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron) is a rank of nobility. so the "not a noble" part of the header doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Yes, this is it!  Thank you.  I suspected Baron's Island was somewhere in the title, but the first few pages of that on google was turning up only RL references.  I appreciate the link, but wonder if posting it is against site policy, it being copywritten material?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I felt like it being freely available on that site was 'ok'. I leave it to the community if it needs to be censored or users to be responsible with its use